# Changing Column Qualifier name in HBase

Tags: hbase

Is to possible to change column qualifier name in `HBase`?

for example:

```
from cf:sales  
to cf:sales_new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way I can find is to add the new column qualifier, then delete the old.

```
hbase> get 'tablename', 'rowkey', {COLUMN => 'colfam:oldqualifier'} value
hbase> put 'tablename', 'rowkey', 'colfam:newqualifier', 'value'
hbase> deleteall 'tablename', 'rowkey', 'colfam:oldqualifier'
```

Found it here: http://qnalist.com/questions/383919/renaming-a-column

Comment: and transferring the data associated?